# Service with a LocationListener not updated the position. What to do?

Tags: android, service, gps

A service which starts at boot with a LocationListener then sends the position and device data to a web service. The code works perfectly when not part of a service, the service but passes only a first position and not updated.

```
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    // Define the criteria how to select the location provider -> use
    // default
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);      
    // Initialize the location fields
    if (location != null) {
            onLocationChanged(location);
            item.LatitudePhone = f_latitude;
            item.LongitudePhone = f_longitude;
            } else {
            item.LatitudePhone = f_latitude;
            item.LongitudePhone = f_longitude;
            }
    item.Active = false; 
    return item;
}

  /* Request updates at startup */
 //   @Override
  protected void onResume() {
 //     super.onResume();
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);
  }

  /* Remove the location listener updates when Activity is paused */
 //   @Override
  protected void onPause() {
 //     super.onPause();
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
  }

  @Override
  public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    f_latitude = (float) (location.getLatitude());
    f_longitude = (float) (location.getLongitude());
  }

  @Override
  public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
  }

  @Override
  public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Enabled new provider " + provider,
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }

  @Override
  public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Disabled provider " + provider,
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
```

Comment: how do you use it in your service？

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the same code as it is in the service, then problem can be because you are telling the listener not to update in OnPause() method: `locationManager.removeUpdates(this);` . So maybe after giving one value it stops updating. Try to remove it, so as to let it update. See what happens. Hope this helps else please comment.

Comment: Not run, latitude and longitude are now appearing with zero value ... I do not understand.